# System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' (showDialog error)

Tags: c#, messagebox, showdialog, bunifu

I am new to c#, I am trying to code a page where select a button it will pass the image and its text to the other page, however, it shows me this error. (I was having an error with the code in Stars)
Sorry i am still new to this soo i dont get what it means.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Parameter is not valid.

(The first code was the image and message to be inserted)

(The second code was for the image and message to be inserted into the first code)

This the first Code

```
public Booking(Image passingimage, string bandtitle)
{           
  InitializeComponent();
  pictureBox1.Image = passingimage;
  bunifuCustomLabel5.Text = bandtitle;
}

public static void Shbooking(string bandtitle, Image passingimage)
{
  Booking bk = new SoftwarePrj_LawZhiMing.Booking (passingimage,bandtitle);
  **bk.ShowDialog();**
}
```

Second Code

```
public partial class EandB : UserControl
{
  Image passingimage;
  public static string passingtitle;

  private void BunifuThinButton21_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ((Home)this.TopLevelControl).Hide();
    passingimage = pictureBox6.Image;
    passingtitle = bunifuCustomLabel2.Text;
    Booking.Shbooking(passingtitle, passingimage);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a constructor with arguments, at least only one. You shoud create two - one is the default:

```
public Booking()
{
    InitialiseComponent();
}
```

And the second constructor is whatever you'd like to:

```
public Booking(Image passingimage, string bandtitle)
{
    InitialiseComponent();
    //Your code goes here
}
```

That's so because the program launches the Form without any arguments. So you have to edit the first code so it has two constructors:

```
public Booking()
{
    InitialiseComponent();
}

public Booking(Image passingimage, string bandtitle)
{
    InitialiseComponent();
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried adding a adding the constructor as u told but it seems like it was flag out/ ignored